# Are the bits of Environment.TickCount a simple uint?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

The [Environment.TickCount docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=net-7.0#remarks) say this:

> Because the value of the TickCount property value is a 32-bit **signed**
> integer,... You can work around this issue by calling the Windows
> **GetTickCount** function... (emphasis added)

Why do they suggest invoking a native function when all that's needed is a simple cast:

```
(uint)Environment.TickCount
```

Unless, of course, `Environment.TickCount` is ***not*** a simple **uint** wrapped in an **int**.

So which one is it, are the docs ignoring a simple solution or is **Environment.TickCount** something else?

Comment: Yes, it is an uint under the hood.  But that's not [CLSCompliant].  The cast will bomb the program with an OverflowException when overflow checking is enabled.  It is not by default, not enough C# programmers are aware of its benefits.  It is in a VB.NET project btw.  Environment.TickCount64 is a simple workaround.

Comment: The suggestion in the docs to use `TickCount64` is more sane than either approach. @HansPassant: that's easily worked around by explicitly using an `unchecked` conversion. Though at this point you're really dealing with C# specifics, which is perhaps why the docs don't mention it, as they usually try to be language neutral (and `uint` is not CLS-compliant).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for verifying that. I'm not using TickCount64 because I want to get the time since `GetLastInputInfo` which seems to return a `uint`. So all I need is to subtract it from the uint of TickCount, (Never using it for more than 50 days or even close to that.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert See my comment above to Hans, I'm specifically using TickCount and not TickCount64. By the way, thanks for the idea of explicitly using unchecked, to avoid any possible problems in the future.

Comment: There is no terribly good reason to use `TickCount` if `TickCount64` is available. If you want to be compatible with things that support no more than 32 bits of it, just mask them off (`Environment.TickCount64 & 0xffff_ffff`); this has the added benefit of making the truncation explicit and forcing you to think, because if `TickCount` wraps around from its maximum value, properly calculating differences is more intricate than just subtracting `uint` values (consider the case where `GetLastInputInfo` returns `0xffff_ffff`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert What would be the problem? `u10 - uMax` is simply 11. (Assuming **u10** is **10** as `TickCount`, and **uMax** is **uint.MaxValue** as `GetLastInputInfo`, because `TickCount` wrapped around and became **10**)